# Does Networkmanager support encrypted private keys?

Tags: encryption, networkmanager, wpa2-eap

I am trying to improve wifi security and recently changed to wpa2 enterprise using eap-ttls. Works fine so far, but I do not like the idea of all passwords (hashed or not) sitting on my radius server. So I want to migrate to eap-tls. This is where I run into problems using network manager. I have properly set up my own certificate authority used to sign all keys (had to do that for eap-ttls already). My radius server is set up correctly and my client has both certificate and key. Now here comes the problem: As long as I use an unencrypted private key I can connect to my wireless network. As soon as I encrypt my private key networkmanager can not establish a connection with my network any more. If I use aes256 I can not even hit the apply button to save my settings. If I use aes128 or des3 I can apply my changes, but not connect. Private key password is correct.
The command to encrypt my key was:

```
openssl rsa -outform pem -in Notebook-key-unenc.pem -out Notebook-key-enc-des3.pem -des3
```

Any suggestions how else I could encrypt my private key and use it with Networkmanager? Using version 1.8.0 in case that matters.

Comment: Have similar problem, too bad Mint power users don't seem to read unix.stackexchange.com